# Network Error While making axios call with Form Data

Tags: react-native, axios

We have an application where we need to upload documents or images:

react: 17.0.2

react-native: 0.68.2

axios: 1.3.2

While making web service call using axios, we are getting Network Error in both iOS and Android.

Same API is working in web and through Postman.

Code (Same code is working fine with Json data.)

```js
            try {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', fileUpload);
                const obj = { hello: "world" };
                formData.append('param', JSON.stringify(obj));
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/fr_webservice/file/doUpload',
                    data: formData,
                    headers: {
                        'x-auth-token': authData.token,
                        Accept: "application/json ,text/plain, */*",
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                    },
                });
                console.log("[Form Data Response]: ", response);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("[Form Data Error]: ", error);
            }
```

```
"AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:191293:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26337:27)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:25607:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:25417:16)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:25543:47
    at EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:1731:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2533:31)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2302:17
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2492:13)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.dbp.employeeone&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2301:14)"
```

Comment: Check if cors added in the API

Comment: Yes, because same API is working in web and through Postman also.

Comment: In Postman API will work fine. You will face problem in integration. Just check with your backend team regarding cors.

Comment: I conformed, CORS is enabled.

Comment: Can you share codesandbox link of your code.